# MSAccess - Total & Avail Memory Stats?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently using the following to report the total memory of  the various clients using my MSAccess app.  I am seeing a wide range of users:  2GB to 32GB.

In addition to total memory, I presume it is also possible to report available memory. Any pointers/API references, please?

```
Public Function SysMemory()
    Dim oInstance
    Dim colInstances
    Dim dRam As Double
    Set colInstances = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory")
    For Each oInstance In colInstances
        dRam = dRam + oInstance.Capacity
    Next
    SysMemory = Int(dRam / 1024 / 1024 / 1000) & "GB"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code, very similar to yours:

```
Sub ShowFreeMemory()
    Dim computerName As String
    computerName = "."

    Dim wmiService As Object
    Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & computerName & "\root\cimv2")

    Dim items As Object
    Set items = wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory", , 48)

    Dim item As Object
    For Each item In items
        Debug.Print "Available GB: " & Round(item.AvailableBytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

I found it here
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/517ae39d-b300-4bdd-8503-9f8699cb4e9d
and reworked it a bit for VBA.

Comment: Nice.  Works just as expected.  Thanks.